# Two example clock window via multithreading/

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simple GUI clock with multithreading.My purpose is making two identical exampl clock window.

```
public class JavaApplication9 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame clock = new TextClockWindow();
    clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    clock.setVisible(true);      
}//end main}
class TextClockWindow extends JFrame {


private JTextField timeField;  // set by timer listener
private JButton listener; 



public TextClockWindow() {
    //  GUI 
    timeField = new JTextField(6);
    timeField.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 48));
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Action");
     add(button1);
             button1.addActionListener((ActionListener) listener);
             ActionListener listener=new ActionListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){setBackground(Color.red );
             }
             };



    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    content.add(timeField); 



    this.setTitle("My_simple_clock");        this.pack();



    // Create a 1-second timer and action listener for it.
    // Specify package because there are two Timer classes
    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,
          new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                  int h = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                  int m = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                  timeField.setText("" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
              }
          });
    t.start();  
}
```

**This is code without multithreading.But wheni trying to use Runnable some error occured.
In method main  Non Static variable cannot be referenced in a static context.**

My code with  multithreading:

```
public class MyClock{
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Runnable r=new Clocks();
   Thread n=new Thread(r);
   n.start();  

}        
public class Clocks implements Runnable {
public Clocks() {}
public void run() {JFrame clock = new TextClockWindow();
    clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    clock.setVisible(true);
    }
```

please help find the reason why it is not work.runnable is writing correctly....

Comment: 1) add "some error" to the question and 2) i believe you can only have one GUI thread but i'm not sure if that's relevant here.

Comment: Yes.I know that GUI have one thread.but iam trying to make applications which  must execute two paralel windows clock.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you declared `Clocks` class as inner class ?

Move your `Clocks` class outside `MyClock` class and remove the `public` qualifier if you're declaring the class in the same file. It will start working.

[image: two intances running]